# regex, search a few letter in one word

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have the following code:

```
my_str = "little"
```

And I need to lookup for the sequence of letters `l..t..e`, in that order, in `my_str`.  Above pattern and my string have to match, because `l..t..e` is exists in my string.

Question is I need to a regex to do it with python.

Comment: `lte` doesn't exits in your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using the regex pattern `l.*t.*e`, e.g.

```
my_str = "little"
if re.match(r'l.*t.*e', my_str):
    print "MATCH"
```

More generally, if you want to find `l..t..e` within a single word, then try:

```
my_str = "little"
if re.match(r'\b\w*l.*t.*e\w*\b', my_str):
    print "MATCH"
```

Comment: A serious question: If  have `olittle` as string, does the above code work?

Comment: It would also match.  Perhaps you want: `\bl.*t.*e\b` ?

Answer (score 0):

The regExpr is

```
l.*t.*e
```

.* means any number of any symbols.
You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) and try [here](http://https:/https://regexr.com/).